Search for documents with similar texts
I have a document with three attributes: tags, location, and text.
Currently, I am indexing all of them using LangChain/pgvector/embeddings.
I have satisfactory results, but I want to know if there is a better way since I want to find one or more documents with a specific tag and location, but the text can vary drastically while still meaning the same thing. I thought about using embeddings/vector databases for this reason.
Would it also be a case of using RAG (Retrieval-Augmented Generation) to "teach" the LLM about some common abbreviations that it doesn't know?
